# Bootstrap Dual listbox and single select with fetching values in alert with add/delete/close option in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css, listbox

Can you please anyone help me how to solve this issue.

Bootstrap have dual listbox option with single/multiple select only.

I need dual listbox with single select.

**Explanation:**

For example:

I have dual listbox,**left listbox** have 5 options. I need single select.(i.e) If i select the single option in the **left listbox**, it shown popup(alert) with fetching the respective field values and also the popup have **Add** or **Cancel** button to add/cancel the values.After clicking the add option in popup it will be added in right list box.

And if i select the option in right listbox , again it shown popup(alert) with fetching the respective field values and also the popup have **Delete** or **Cancel** button to delete/cancel the values in the right listbox.

Please any one give solution to this problem,

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

```
//Html
<select id="sel1">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<select id="sel2"></select>
//This is the JS
//On change of the first select
$('#sel1').on('change', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var selVal = $(this).val();
    var selHtml = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
    moveItem('#sel1', '#sel2', selVal, selHtml);//call our function
});
//On change of the second select
$('#sel2').on('change', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var selVal = $(this).val();
    var selHtml = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
    moveItem('#sel2', '#sel1', selVal, selHtml);//call our function
});
//Move function take 4 parameters
function moveItem(moveFrom, moveTo, selVal, selHtml) {
    if (confirm("Are you sure? : " + selVal)) {//Confirm dialogue box comes up and on selecting 'ok' this part will be executed
        $(moveTo).append('<option value="' + selVal + '">' + selHtml + '</option>');//append a value to select
        var mId = moveFrom + ' option[value="' + selVal + '"]';
        $(mId).remove();//remove value from the other select
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Hi                                                                   I tried this above code, It accepts multi select with popup option.But i need single select i.e it accepts to add only one option field at a time. And also i have to show all option in the list after click add option in the left listbox. In the right list box i have show only the added list after the page refreshing. Please help me how to solve. Thanks alot for anwering.

Comment: Hi please anyone help me to solve the above scenario.

Comment: If I understand correctly, what you want it :
- User can select only one option from the First select box 
- And only that option is moved to the Second select box
- The First select box should retain the value
- You want the value to be there after refresh the page

Comment: Yes you are correct.After refreshing the page, the second select box should have the added values. I tried the above code, it has multiple select but i need single select.And in the left selectbox popup have Add/Cancel option. And right selectbox popup have Remove/Cancel option. Please help me hove to solve this. Thanks.