# Bootstrap Dual listbox and single select with add/remove/cancel option in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Please refer the below link and give a solution to solve the issues.I have tried the code in this link:

[Bootstrap Dual listbox and single select with fetching values in alert with add/delete/close option in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25447664/bootstrap-dual-listbox-and-single-select-with-fetching-values-in-alert-with-add)

Explanation:

1. Need to enable single select in dual list box not multiple select.

I have dual listbox,left listbox have 5 options. I need only single select not multiple select.(i.e) If i select the single option in the left listbox, it shown popup(alert) with fetching the respective field values and also the popup have **Add or Cancel button** to add the values.After clicking the add option in popup it will be added in right list box. But the left list box have to show all the options in the list.

And if i select the option in right listbox , again it shown popup(alert) with fetching the respective field values and also the popup have **Remove or Cancel button** to delete the values in the right listbox.After deleting the values in the right list box (added values have shown in the right list box)i.e after the page refreshing except remove values shown in right list box.

Note: Left list box popup have **Add and cancel option**. Right list box popup have Remove and cancel option. Please any one give solution to this problem,

Thanks.